# Nginx disable folder slash redirection

Tags: nginx, redirect

How to disable when go to /folder >> /folder/ slash redirection? I want to /folder >> /folder (no slah redirection.)

Comment: There must not be a folder at that URL path.

Comment: What do you want Nginx to do with that URI instead? What you are describing is the default action for URIs that match a directory name.